# PHP Mailer returns SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server

Tags: php

I tried to change port number and 'ssl' to 'tls'. I also activated extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini, restarted the server and allowed the low security applications on Gmail (https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)
These solutions seem to work for everyone but not me! can you help? here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbConnector.php';

$toAddress = $_POST['toEmail'];
$emailSubject = $_POST['subject'];
$emailContent = $_POST['content'];
$fromPassword = $_POST['frompassword'];
require 'PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require 'PHPMailer-master/class.smtp.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail -> IsSMTP();
$mail -> SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail -> SMTPAuth = true;
$mail -> SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail -> HOST = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail -> Port = 465; //587
$mail -> IsHTML(true);
$mail -> Username = $_SESSION['loggedUserEmail'];
$mail -> Password = $fromPassword;
$mail -> SetFrom($_SESSION['loggedUserEmail']);
$mail -> Subject = $emailSubject;
$mail -> Body = $emailContent;
$mail -> AddAddress($toAddress);

if(!$mail -> Send ())
{
    echo "Your mail has not been sent!";
}
else
{
    echo "Your email has been sent successfully!";
}
?>
```

Comment: change the port to 80 and check

Comment: nothing happened :(

Comment: the connect error is probably for the session and post things, can you verify by printing them? that they are actually there or not

Comment: Already did that ... all the variables have the correct values ... 
I think there should be something in php.ini other than openssl library to be modified but I have no idea what!

Comment: is your localhost allowed to access public network through the firewall? and also your internet connection?

Comment: I'm using WAMPSERVER can you tell me how to check this?

Comment: search for allowing localhost to access public network and also the internet connection in windows

Comment: unfortunately nothing...

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2

go through this and try again, may be google is not allowing normal setup now, you need auth toke to be created

Comment: first try this command in cmd and see if you get reply ping smtp.gmail.com

Comment: and also check this link to troubleshoot more https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: I got reply for the ping

Comment: then check the both links and try because i think it might be ouath problem which is not allowing you to connect to the gmail server